# how to check my input text using ActionScript 3 using a button?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I'm pretty new to action script 3 and came across a problem with a function i'm establishing. Every time I test out to see if it gives me a true statement and the if argument it claims its false (the frgo3 button). Here is the code:

```
var check:Boolean = false;
var input1:String;
var answer:String = "New_York_Harbor";

fr1check.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, checkfr);
frgo3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, Moveonfr);
frno3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, Movenofr);

function checkfr(event:MouseEvent):void{
    input1= frin.text;
    check = true;
    if(input1 == answer){
     frgo3.visible = true;}
    else  (
    {frno3.visible = false;}
}

function Moveonfr(event:MouseEvent): void{
    score =score +100;
        gotoAndPlay(5);
}

function Movenofr(event:MouseEvent): void{
gotoAndPlay(5);
}
```

How would I go about resolving this problem?

Comment: because the value of your text box would be "true" (string type) while you're comparing it to the value of true (boolean) since "true" does not equal true, it will return false. You need to either convert the string to a boolean, or compare it to "true"

Comment: Your code is a mess. What's the `(` after else?! You can simply do a `trace (frin.text);` in order to check what's the input, and to be sure it is the same as you are checking. It's the fr1check button with the `checkfr` function, not the `frgo3`. FORMAT your code and ask your question properly!